# Multiple SELECT COUNT from different tables mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I want to count the number of images with prefix PublicImg from different two tables, so I used this code:

```
    $nb_imgs_a_afficher = $BDD->query("
                                    SELECT COUNT(ID,img_kind) 
                                    FROM images_public  

                                    UNION

                                    SELECT COUNT(ID,img_kind) 
                                    FROM images_users  

                                    WHERE img_kind='PublicImg'");

    $images_users = $nb_imgs_a_afficher->fetch();
```

But I receive this error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' in C:\wamp1\www\website\Index_Public_Images\public_images.php on line 72

Well, before I had one table that was easy with:

```
$nb_imgs_a_afficher = $BDD->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb_imgs FROM images_users WHERE img_kind='PublicImg'  ");
```

Comment: `SLECET` might be a problem here.

Comment: SELECT COUNT ... + SELECT COUNT ... ? I think you need the plus operator (+) instead of UNION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have a typo there. Change `SLECET` to `SELECT` and then if you are trying to get a sum of rows from two different table use -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT ID,img_kind
            FROM images_public  
            UNION
    SELECT ID,img_kind
            FROM images_users  
            WHERE img_kind='PublicImg' ) x
```

Not sure if you meant to have the `WHERE` clause on both queries. If so, add `WHERE img_kind='PublicImg'` before the `UNION` as well.

Also, check for duplicates. `UNION` removes duplicates where as `UNION ALL` doesn't.